# Debug Google Slides via API

Tags: google-workspace, google-slides-api

Google Slides presentation and slides structure are very specific, it's quite different from HTML/CSS representation of values.
For example, to create and to position of an element, You should do something [like this](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/add-shape) :

```
var requests = [{
  createShape: {
    objectId: elementId,
    shapeType: 'TEXT_BOX',
    elementProperties: {
      pageObjectId: pageId,
      size: {
        height: pt350,
        width: pt350
      },
      transform: {
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        translateX: 350,
        translateY: 100,
        unit: 'PT'
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  insertText: {
    objectId: elementId,
    insertionIndex: 0,
    text: 'New Box Text Inserted!'
  }
}];
```

But as I need to create something rather complex, I would like to be able to create it via Google Slides interface, dump it after, and to import it into my code for further slides automatic creation.

Is there are some ways to dump the structure / code of a presentation ?

Didn't found any API resources about it.

Comment: You want to retrieve the information of objects at each slides. If my understanding is correct, how about using presentations.get of Slides API? https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get Using this, you can retrieve them. If you need, I would like to propose a sample endpoint. If I misunderstand what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/gsuitedevs/md2googleslides it's creating slides from Markdown structure